# removing xmlns in XElement

Tags: xelement

I am parsing a XML string in XElement.Parse("somestring") and insert it into another XElement using add method. so, i want to remove the default utf encoding and xmlns attributs from "somestring" text.

How to do that...

I appreciate your help.

Thanks
KJ

Comment: Do you mean the encoding="UTF-8" on the xml declaration?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have an XML document including an `<?xml` declaration.  Use the `XDocument` instead to parse:-

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(someString);
existingElem.Add(doc.Root);
```

As for xmlns try the above and see what you get, I don't think you need worry about.  It may only be an issue if your existing document uses a default namespace which differs from your included XML.

Comment: Hello,

Thanks for your swift reply, it does answer my query.

Thanks
KJ